# Optics: mirror equation

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I have seen the derivation of the mirror equation from concave lenses using similar triangles but I cannot derive it from convex mirror ray diagram, how do I prove this equation works for a convex mirror?[image: ray diagram of convex mirror]

Comment: It might be helpful if you can provide a diagram that shows how you are setting up the problem and trying to solve it.  I hope this helps.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I think your question would be better-received if you showed your effort in answering the question yourself.

Comment: try using the ray going through P instead the one going trough  C

Comment: @trula, Right: that makes the triangles much easier to work with.